# I can't understand the following script

Tags: jquery, html

As I'm new to jQuery I found this script which is useful for my project. I want to fade the image inside the container.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#collage-container img").mouseover(function(){
            $("#collage-container img").css("z-index",1);
            $(this).css("z-index",999);
        $(this).fadeOut(100,function(){ $(this).fadeIn(1000);  });
         });
    });
</script>
```

It's hard to understand line 4 and 5. Is line 5 the image?

Comment: if i want to put multiple image inside gallery what should i do. can anyone provide sample code for my query

Comment: I think you need to read about how [jQuery works](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works) and [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html), at the absolute minimum. Ideally, read about the CSS selectors first, and then move to jQuery.

Comment: This is not PHP, even though you may be using PHP to serve that page.

Answer (score 2):

The `$(this)` in the callback function is `$("#collage-container img")`, you could rewrite your code like below . By the way, line4 has no sence, it set the z-index to 1, but line 5 set z-index again to 999.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#collage-container img").mouseover(function () {
           $(this).css("z-index", 999).fadeOut(100, function () {
               $(this).fadeIn(1000);
           });
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 4 sets the z-index property, which has to do with layers. Layers with a higher z-index will flow over layers with a lower z-index. z-index 1 is a low value so I'm guessing the image is getting pushed to the back. But I also think that `this` on line 5 refers to the same element, so it's immediately assigned a z-index of `999` as well (which is quite high).

It seems a bit non-sensicle but maybe it's a workaround for some bug?

Answer (score 0):

line4: Setting the z-index of matched images `#collage-container img` to 1.
line5: **this** refers in this case to `#collage-container img`; setting the z-index to 999.

The lines are part of the `mouseover` function.

Answer (score 0):

First have a look at line 3, it says: "When the mouse is over an image in the collage-contatiner the function will be executed."

Line 4,5,6 is inside the function and *this* inside the function referers to the element that trigged the function (in this case the image).
Line 5 says, set the z-index to 999 which bring the image to the front.