# How to reduce the size of magnifier in as3 via coding

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Im newbie to flash,as3.Im learning flash through flepstudio tutorial. I got this code from tere site. **Now i plan to reduce the size of magnifier**. I dont know where to reduce the size of maginifer obj through coding.this is following code.

```
private function createClips():void
        {
            circle_mc=new Circle();
            addChild(circle_mc);

            container_mc=new MovieClip();
            addChild(container_mc);

            mask_mc=new Circle();
            addChild(mask_mc);

            glass_mc=new Glass();
            addChild(glass_mc);
        }

        private function initGlass():void
        {
            bit_1=new BitmapData(loader.width,loader.height,false,0x00FFFFFF);
            bit_2=new BitmapData(circle_mc.width,circle_mc.height,false,0x00FFFFFF);
            bit_3=new BitmapData(300,300,true,0x00FFFFFF);

            disp_filter=new DisplacementMapFilter(bit_2,new Point(0,0),1,1,50,50);

            loader.width/=2;
            loader.height/=2;

            circle_mc.visible=false;
            container_mc.mask=mask_mc;

            bit_1.draw(loader);
            bit_2.draw(circle_mc);

            var b:Bitmap=new Bitmap(bit_3)
            container_mc.addChild(b);
        }

        private function magnify(evt:Event):void
        {
            var distance:Number=mask_mc.width/2;

            container_mc.x=mouseX-distance;
            container_mc.y=mouseY-distance;
            mask_mc.x=mouseX-distance;
            mask_mc.y=mouseY-distance;
            glass_mc.x=mouseX;
            glass_mc.y=mouseY;

            bit_3.copyPixels(bit_1,new Rectangle(mouseX*2-distance,mouseY*2-distance*1.5,200,200),new Point(0,0))
            bit_3.applyFilter(bit_3,bit_3.rect,new Point(0,0),disp_filter)
        }
    }

If i reduce this size of maginifier i can able to finish my homework. :)
```

Comment: its k richie. Is it possible to reduce the size of the object via coding ???

Comment: and meanwhile, you post another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751251/i-cant-understand-the-following-script. I think you should read the FAQ section of this site

Answer (score 0):

Please reduce the mask MC size before apply as a mask. your problem will be resolved.